# Как в Android Studio создавать установочный apk файл?

Tags: android, android-sdk

"Build - Generate Signed APK", а дальше что? Там окошко  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его заполнять?
Я попробовал просто вставить значение "1", чтобы пропустило дальше, но ничего не вышло, конце выдало ошибку.

Comment: Что если на help в окошке нажать

Comment: Хороший вариант, сейчас нажму. Только есть проблема, я второй день использую программу и от того что я там прочитаю я все равно не пойму суть, что к чему.

Comment: Для того, чтобы создать установочный .apk, вам нужно подписать его собственным ключом разработчика. Из вашего вопроса очевидно, что такого ключа у вас нет, поэтому нажмите на: `Create New`, чтобы сгенирировать такой ключ, заполнив необходимые поля появившейся формы, а затем уже в этом окне надо будет указать путь до сгенерированного ключа и ту информацию, которую вы использовали для его генерации ( пароль и тд).

Comment: Вот теперь я получил папку "app" с файлами, что теперь необходимо сделать чтобы это установить на мой смартфон?

Comment: [Инструкция с картинками (русский язык)](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/publish.php)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Если вы хотите просто установить приложение на телефон, для проверки его функционала, то вам надо зайти в папку, где у вас хранится проект и зайти в папку `app\build\outputs`, там у вас будет файл app-debug.apk.
Этот файл вы копируете на свой телефон и через программу fileManager находите ее и устанавливаете.
То что вы делали, это нужно для того, чтобы создать уникальный сертификат для вашего приложения (это нужно для того чтобы выложить приложение в Google play Market).

P.C. не копируйте файл app-debug-unaligned. При каждом компилировании проекта у вас будет обновляться ваш файл app-debug.apk

Comment: Запятые? Не, не слышал ... Можно просто использовать устройство в качестве отладочного и тогда для того, чтобы установить приложение нужно просто нажать "Run".

Answer (score 3):

Пробовал загрузить приложение по ответу выше, телефон устанавливал приложение, но оно вылетало, что бы такого не было нажимаем Build->Build apk->открываем ...\app\build\outputs (или просто жмём show apk) и только после этого ваше приложение адекватно откроется на вашем смартфоне