# Запустить готовое приложение на реальном девайсе

Tags: android

Есть практически готовое приложение в Android Studiо, которое прекрасно запускается в эмуляторе на любом девайсе. Однако я хочу запустить приложение на своем телефоне, без того чтобы подключать свой телефон через USB и запускать из проекта. Можно как то создать APK файл, чтобы при желании можно было закинуть на любой телефон и запустить? 
Проблема в том что я не знаю где найти в проекте тот apk файл чтобы залить на телефон и установить там приложение.

Comment: В чем проблема?

Comment: конечно можно, иначе как бы мы заливали свои проекты в тот же google play

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю, где взять этот apk файл чтобы залить на телефон.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434251/Как-в-android-studio-создавать-установочный-apk-файл

Comment: Я даже видео нашёл https://youtu.be/seOcMllYBkA

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось